# GCP: Calling a Cloud Function via API Gateway using a Google ID received from 'Sign In With Google for Web'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-gateway, sign-in-with-google

[image]

Hi, I’m wondering if the above diagram is something that is even possible with GCP. I’ve been able to get to the point where if the Cloud Function (3) is configured to require authentication, I get a 403 Forbidden, whereas if I turn off require authentication the call is successful.

My goal is to NOT have the Cloud Function publicly accessible.

I believe all service accounts have been granted the necessary Cloud Invoker roles. If the service accounts didn’t have the proper roles to invoke the cloud function, then I would expect it not to work even when the function was configured to not require authentication. However, there are a lot of places where the service account needs to be specified, e.g. on the GCP gateway, the gateway config file and the api - so maybe there is an option I missed?

My API Gateway (2) is configured to allow the Google ID tokens to authenticate users as described here: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-googleid

Finally, I’m using the ‘Sign In with Google For Web’ (1) as described here:  https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview and using the `credential` returned in using the Javascript API to call the endpoint specified in the API Gateway.

Any help is appreciated!

Quick Edit: In (1), I call the API Gateway either by adding a header of `Authorization: Bearer $(credential_returned_from_sign)` to my HTTP call, or, to speed things while testing, I have been copy & pasting the returned credential in Postman and placing the credential in the Authorization >> Bearer Token screen with a Postman request.

Edit No. 2: I've created a small github jist with the details of how I'm calling the API Gateway from the browser as well as the config file that I'm using to configure my api gateway in this Jist: https://gist.github.com/nealgriffin/5110690d1b0fcba457cd26ab2ecb3dbf and if any of the details there are helpful, I'll update this question with those details.

Comment: Can you share how you call API Gateway? The 403 error code means you have not added  the authorization token in the request header. If it was a permission/role issue, you would have 401 error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your question ( and thank you for all of your other thoughtful answers on this topic - I've read most of them). I edited the question above to reflect how I'm calling API Gateway. I'm placing the credential from Sign In with Google in an Authorization: Bearer $()` header.

Comment: Can you share also the endpoint where you use your security definition?

Comment: Of course, I honestly wasn't totally sure what you meant by security definition ( I was thinking config file used to configure the API Gateway ) so I attached that into a jist in the original question. I'll update my question with the specific if any of those provide to be helpful - thank you again!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you try the alternative with the access_token URL parameter?

Comment: I hadn't. It was my belief that securing the API Gateway with a key (the interaction between (1) and (2) in the diagram above ) would still require me to leave the Cloud Function (3) in an `allow unauthenticated` state. However, this is an excellent suggestion to try - I'll give that a try later on today and see if there is a way for me to inspect the authorization header that is passed to the Cloud Function for clues / alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact opposite, my Cloud Function can only be called using identity token. But from my API Gateway I can go to the configured path without token and I get the same response.